# fgets error and strings declaration style on c

Tags: c

I'm curious about one thing, the following code works perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  FILE * fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  char line[100];

  while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL )
    fputs(line, stdout);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

But why it is not possible to use instead:

```
char *line;
```

Without causing fgets to crash?

Comment: "works perfectly" is an interesting claim for code which can easily be made to segfault.

Comment: how can that be achieved?

Comment: If 'test.txt' does not exist or is not readable, fopen will fail and fgets will segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets` crashes because it is writing the result into *unallocated memory*.

Without any further memory allocation, `char *line` points to "nothing". It points to *something*, but not to any valid memory location -- `null` if your compiler sets uninitialized values to `0`, or any *random* memory location anywhere on or not on your system.

Even if `fgets` does *not* crash, you cannot predict what it does as writing into unallocated memory results in **undefined behavior** ([What is undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)).

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Just point it to some valid memory.

```
char line[100];
char* linep = line ;
while( fgets(linep, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL )...
```

If you don't assing line to linep, then linep points to random memory, and you cannot use that.

Answer (score 1):

`char *line` and `char line[100]` don't mean the same.
The first is a pointer to a `char`, we don't know if it will be a single char or an array of chars it is pointing to. The second on the other hand is an array.

[`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) needs a valid location to write to. In this case, `char *line` doesn't have any valid location to point at, whereas `char line[100]` is a valid char array location

Comment: You seem to be confusing "stream" and "buffer".